# Upper bound of joint probability of two RVs $X$ and $Y$, $\mathbb P(X<Y_1,..., X<Y_n)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables and they are independent.
They are following their own distributions, for example, $X$ follows $\mathcal{D}_{X}$.

Let me draw a sample from the distribution $\mathcal{D}_{X}$ and call it $X_1$.
I know that the probability $\mathbb P(X_1 < Y_1) = a$.

However, now I want to pick more samples from $\mathcal{D}_{Y}$, for example, I sample $n$ instances, $Y_1,..., Y_n$.

I would like to make an upper bound of $\mathbb P(X_1<Y_1, X_1<Y_2,..., X_1<Y_n)$ in terms of $a$.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

---

One of my trial
$$\mathbb P(X_1<Y_1, ..., X_1<Y_n) = \sum_{x} \mathbb P\left(X_1<Y_1, ..., X_1<Y_n \mid X_1=x\right)\mathbb P(X_1=x) = \sum_x {\mathbb P(x<Y)}^n \mathbb P(X_1=x),$$ but hard to link it to $a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an upper bound, the best that you can do is
$$
\Pr(X_1 < Y_1 , \dotsc, X_1 < Y_n)
\leq \Pr(X_1 < Y_1)
= a.
$$

To see that this is tight for any $a$, let $X \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(1 - a)$ and $Y_n = 1/2$ so that
$$
\Pr(X_1 < Y_1 , \dotsc, X_1 < Y_n)
= \Pr(X_1 = 0)
= a.
$$

More interesting is a lower bound, that follows from Jensen's inequality.
Since $X_1$ is independent from the $Y_i$, we have
\begin{align*}
\Pr(X_1 < Y_1 , \dotsc, X_1 < Y_n)
&= \mathbf{E}[\Pr(X_1 < Y_1| X_1)^n ] \\
&\geq \mathbf{E}[\Pr(X_1 < Y_1 | X_1)]^n \\
&= \Pr(X_1 < Y_1)^n \\
&= a^n .
\end{align*}

This bound is also tight, which follows from taking $X_1 = 1 - a$ and $Y_n \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(0, 1)$.